# Fonts not antialiased under Ubuntu with Qt4 static build

Tags: qt, ubuntu, fonts, qt4

I needed to port a Windows Qt app to Linux and Mac. Under Mac all is fine but with Ubuntu (tried both 16.04.1 and 14.04 on 2 different machines) the fonts are not antialised. See this picture:

[image]

With the dynamic Qt libs all is fine. It only happens when I'm using the Qt static libs. Here's how I'm building Qt statically:

```
./configure -static -prefix /home/.../Desktop/Qt-4.8.7-static -no-sql-sqlite -no-sql-sqlite2 --platform=linux-g++-32
make
make install
```

The output above is generated with the standard Qt Widgets template from Qt Creator to which I'm adding:

```
QMessageBox::information(this, "Horrendous font", "This is one fugly font");
```

There is no additional code that could be responsible for this. Any idea why this is happening?